# alternating class in ng-repeat using scope var without binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a nested ng-repeat on a table. It is an accordion table with child rows for each parent row. In order to accomplish this I created a `<tbody>` for each parent item, placing the parent row in a `<tr>` and then using `ng-repeat` to add all the child rows. Due to the multiple `<tbody>` elements the zebra striping on the table gets thrown off. Another wrinkle is that the table has the ability to collapse/expand child rows and I need the striping to be correct for **whichever rows are visible**. So I am trying to manually add striping classes. I'm using Angular's `ng-init` to toggle a scope variable, and then using `ng-class` to apply it. The problem is that it appears to be bound to the final state of the variable rather than what it was as the iterator was rendering the row.

HTML:

```
    <tbody ng-repeat="parentRow in myData" ng-init="changeRowClass($even)">
        <tr ng-class="{'industry-payments-even-row':industryRowEven,'industry-payments-odd-row':!industryRowEven}">
            <td>{{parentRow.industryCode}} - {{parentRow.industryCodeDescription}}</td>
            <td class="numeric">{{parentRow.ValueOneSum}}</td>
            <td class="numeric">{{parentRow.ValueTwoSum}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="childRow in parentRow.childIndustries" ng-init="changeRowClass($even)" ng-class="{'industry-payments-even-row':industryRowEven,'industry-payments-odd-row':!industryRowEven}">
            <td>{{childRow.industryCode}} - {{childRow.industryCodeDescription}}</td>
            <td class="numeric">{{childRow.ValueOne}}</td>
            <td class="numeric">{{childRow.ValueTwo}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Controller code:

```
$scope.industryRowEven = false;
$scope.changeRowClass = function(isEven) {
    $scope.industryRowEven = isEven;
};
```

I need each iteration (of parent OR child) to reverse the class for the next one (*I'm leaving out the issue of if the child is visible or not for now to keep this more simple*). I can see in the debugger that the variable is getting toggled properly on each iteration. The problem is that the `ng-class` seems to be bound to the current state in scope so when it is true it would apply one class, but then next time it is false and switches the class for all of them.

I need it to just print the class according to the variable state at the time it renders that row, and then ignore the variable unless the ng-repeat is started over (like for sorting or toggling visibility, etc.)

Is there a way to stop the binding?

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS has this build in with directives called [ngClassOdd](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClassOdd) and [ngClassEven](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClassEven).

They work just like ngClass, but only on odd/even items inside an ngRepeat.

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work due to the nested ng-repeat. I need the child row to alternate the same row class as the parent to avoid having a child row end up having the same color as the next parent underneath it.

Comment: Then your best bet is using some advanced CSS selectors like .myOddRow:nth-child, etc.